# Why cant I draw anything on my SurfaceView canvas?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas

I tried to match LunarLander's implementation of a SurfaceView style of drawing.

I am starting really simple, and just trying to draw circles underneath the user's touch input, but I can't seem to draw anything! **All my app gets is a green screen (which is the background color of the view in the layout xml)**.

In an attempt to draw something, I have tried drawing a black rectangle on the entire canvas, a circle at 0,0 and a bitmap image. None of these draws succeed. They all get called, and none throw exceptions, but the screen never changes from green.

I am at wits end trying to figure this out so here is my code (minus the game engine, which is irrelevant at this point).

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.jknight.particletoy.view.GameEngineView
          android:id="@+id/gameengineview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#FF66FF33"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT:
Figured it out:

You cannot have a background color property in the layout for a surface view. It was rendering overtop.